# Why does the time appear in this query result

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In the following code, I use `trunc(date)` in the query, because I am only interested in the date, not the time.

However, I get this printed :

`[2019-11-28 00:00:00=653]` instead of `[2019-11-28=653]`.

Here is the code :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = jdbcTemplate.query("select trunc(closing_date) as closing_date, count(*) as total from some_table group by closing_date", new ResultSetExtractor<Map>() {
    @Override
    public Map extractData(ResultSet rs) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> mapRet = new HashMap<>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            mapRet.put(rs.getString("closing_date"), rs.getInt("total"));
        }
        return mapRet;
    }
});
LOGGER.info(Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray()));
```

Why ?

Comment: Can you show us the example of your closing_date column value ? Thanks!

Comment: Also please do inform us what is your date format. You can find that out with this query : `select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`

Comment: Don't know precisely, but you can do also the formatting to string in the query, that should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRUNC()` removes the time element of a date in the sense that it rounds the time down to midnight (in the same way that `trunc(23.42)` gives us `23`). But Oracle DATE is still actually a **datetime** and so there's a time element to display, unless we use a format mask which only shows the date element.

Answer (score 1):

Trunc function only truncate the date. It do not change the display format.

You can use `to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` to display date according to your requirement.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

While connecting from Java to Oracle database, If you can pass below Alter session command, then it can resolve your issue.

Alter Session Set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY';